# Save RTP vp8 stream to webm file

Tags: java, rtp, vp8

I have saved an RTP (with vp8 codec) stream on a file. Now I need to add the header information, to obtain a valid webm file. How I can add the video meta info?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you solve your problem ? Also How did you save vp8 stream from RTP packets ?